# SQLAlchemy query returning results with values outside filter criteria

Tags: sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy to access an SQLite db.  I have populated the database with 50,000 entries as defined by the Event ORM below.  When I query the database and filter for 'time' greater than some value, I consistently get results with time values before the requested time.
How do I craft the query such that if properly filters based on time?

Here is my query code:

```
query = session.query(Event)
query = query.filter(Event.time > starttime)
```

Here is the Event ORM

```
Base = declarative_base()

class Event (Base):
  __tablename__ = 'events'
  eventid = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer, primary_key=True)
  time = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer)
  value = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Float)
#end class
```

Comment: What is `time`? A timestamp? Have you tried the same example just with a lower count of rows (it shouldn't be a problem but maybe it is)? Is it possible to deduce a small dataset that contains the problem?

Comment: 'time' is a tiemstamp (millisec since epoch).
I have generated sample data sets that work (even large ones).  I'm trying to narrow it down to a simple repeatable cause; haven't been able to yet.

Comment: Turn on output on the engine by using `echo=True` on `create_engine` and that execute that exact statement without SQLAlchemy and see if it still produces wrong results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model `Event.time`. is an `Integer Column` if you want to filter by a date time object you have to change the column of use datetime object to filter.

```
from sqlalchemy import func
from dateutil import tz

time = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), nullable=False,
                              server_default=func.now())
starttime = datetime.datetime.now(tz=tz.tzlocal()) # local timezone

query = session.query(Event).filter(Event.time > starttime)
```